# MQL4 Object Label Line break?

Tags: mql4

I am having a problem with line break in object label in mql4?? the "/n" is not working.

is there other way??

I want to show in chart,

Text 1
Text 2
Text 3,

Thanks in advance experts.

Comment: You cannot have line breaks in text objects "\r\n". You simple create separate objects for each line of text you want and change the position/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is "\n" for mql4/mql5

Answer (score 3):

The actual escape sequence to use for a new line is as per the following example:

```
Comment("Line1\r\nLine2");
```

However you can not have line breaks in Objects. You should instead make a separate object for each line. For example:

```
string id="ObjectName1";
ObjectCreate    (0, id, OBJ_LABEL, 0, 0, 0);
ObjectSet       (id, OBJPROP_CORNER, 0);
ObjectSet       (id, OBJPROP_XDISTANCE, 10);
ObjectSet       (id, OBJPROP_YDISTANCE, 10);
ObjectSetText   (id, "Line 1", 10, "Arial", clrBlack);

id="ObjectName2";
ObjectCreate    (0, id, OBJ_LABEL, 0, 0, 0);
ObjectSet       (id, OBJPROP_CORNER, 0);
ObjectSet       (id, OBJPROP_XDISTANCE, 10);
ObjectSet       (id, OBJPROP_YDISTANCE, 20);
ObjectSetText   (id, "Line 1", 10, "Arial", clrBlack);
```